# Sending mail without external mail client in Android

Tags: android, email

I've been working with this for a while in a link from

http://www.jondev.net/articles/Sending_Emails_without_User_Intervention_%28no_Intents%29_in_Android.

I've imported the 3 main library files into lib folder, and copy the whole code as it directs.

and I couldn't get it work for this part below. Can anyone help out? OnCreate, setContentView, findViewById, and MailApp have problems. Or can anyone teach me how can I get this code works?

```
  public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) { 
  super.onCreate(icicle); 
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 

  Button addImage = (Button) findViewById(R.id.send); 
  addImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 
    public void onClick(View view) { 
      Mail m = new Mail("gmailusername@gmail.com", "password"); 

      String[] toArr = {"bla@bla.com", "lala@lala.com"}; 
      m.setTo(toArr); 
      m.setFrom("wooo@wooo.com"); 
      m.setSubject("This is an email sent using my Mail JavaMail wrapper from an Android device."); 
      m.setBody("Email body."); 

      try { 
        m.addAttachment("/sdcard/filelocation"); 

        if(m.send()) { 
          Toast.makeText(MailApp.this, "Email was sent successfully.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
        } else { 
          Toast.makeText(MailApp.this, "Email was not sent.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
        } 
      } catch(Exception e) { 
        //Toast.makeText(MailApp.this, "There was a problem sending the email.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
        Log.e("MailApp", "Could not send email", e); 
      } 
    } 
  }); 
}
```

Comment: Yes @RanjitPati, I tried the code and OnCreate, setContentView, findViewById, and MailApp have problems. I dunno why. I'm a rookie in android.. please help me sir. :)

Comment: can you show your logcat error..

Comment: http://i59.tinypic.com/2mme3ps.jpg , this is the problem of my code

Comment: as i understand..no classes are able to import perfectly..i think you just copy and paste the code from the link..right?

Comment: Yes, I copy and paste the code in. I not sure how to do this.

Comment: just create a new application and add the mail class how i defined below..and in your activity's oncreate method add the 2nd part..and also give internet permission in manifest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do like this:

> Mail.java

```
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Properties;
import javax.activation.CommandMap;
import javax.activation.DataHandler;
import javax.activation.FileDataSource;
import javax.activation.MailcapCommandMap;
import javax.mail.BodyPart;
import javax.mail.Multipart;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart;

public class Mail extends javax.mail.Authenticator {
private String _user;
private String _pass;

private String[] _to;
private String _from;

private String _port;
private String _sport;

private String _host;

private String _subject;
private String _body;

private boolean _auth;

private boolean _debuggable;

private Multipart _multipart;

public Mail() {
    _host = "smtp.gmail.com"; // default smtp server
    _port = "465"; // default smtp port
    _sport = "465"; // default socketfactory port

    _user = ""; // username
    _pass = ""; // password
    _from = ""; // email sent from
    _subject = ""; // email subject
    _body = ""; // email body

    _debuggable = false; // debug mode on or off - default off
    _auth = true; // smtp authentication - default on

    _multipart = new MimeMultipart();

    // There is something wrong with MailCap, javamail can not find a
    // handler for the multipart/mixed part, so this bit needs to be added.
    MailcapCommandMap mc = (MailcapCommandMap) CommandMap
            .getDefaultCommandMap();
    mc.addMailcap("text/html;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_html");
    mc.addMailcap("text/xml;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_xml");
    mc.addMailcap("text/plain;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_plain");
    mc.addMailcap("multipart/*;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.multipart_mixed");
    mc.addMailcap("message/rfc822;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.message_rfc822");
    CommandMap.setDefaultCommandMap(mc);
}

public Mail(String user, String pass) {
    this();

    _user = user;
    _pass = pass;
}

public boolean send() throws Exception {
    Properties props = _setProperties();

    if (!_user.equals("") && !_pass.equals("") && _to.length > 0
            && !_from.equals("") && !_subject.equals("")
            && !_body.equals("")) {
        javax.mail.Session session = javax.mail.Session.getInstance(props,
                this);

        MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session);

        msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(_from));

        InternetAddress[] addressTo = new InternetAddress[_to.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < _to.length; i++) {
            addressTo[i] = new InternetAddress(_to[i]);
        }
        msg.setRecipients(MimeMessage.RecipientType.TO, addressTo);

        msg.setSubject(_subject);
        msg.setSentDate(new Date());

        // setup message body
        BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
        messageBodyPart.setText(_body);
        _multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

        // Put parts in message
        msg.setContent(_multipart);

        // send email
        Transport.send(msg);
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

public void addAttachment(String filename) throws Exception {
    BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
    javax.activation.DataSource source = new FileDataSource(filename);
    messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(
            (javax.activation.DataSource) source));
    messageBodyPart.setFileName(filename);

    _multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
}

@Override
public javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
    return new javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication(_user, _pass);
}

private Properties _setProperties() {
    Properties props = new Properties();

    props.put("mail.smtp.host", _host);

    if (_debuggable) {
        props.put("mail.debug", "true");
    }

    if (_auth) {
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    }

    props.put("mail.smtp.port", _port);
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", _sport);
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class",
            "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");

    return props;
}

// the getters and setters
public String getBody() {
    return _body;
}

public void setBody(String _body) {
    this._body = _body;
}

public String[] getTo() {
    return _to;
}

public void setTo(String[] _to) {
    this._to = _to;
}

public String getFrom() {
    return _from;
}

public void setFrom(String _from) {
    this._from = _from;
}

public String getSubject() {
    return _subject;
}

public void setSubject(String _subject) {
    this._subject = _subject;
}
}
```

In your Activity write the following on any button click:

```
Thread thread = new Thread(){
            @Override
            public void run() {                 
                super.run();
                //Just put your emailId and password here
                Mail m = new Mail(your_emailId,your_password);

                //Array of emailIds where you want to sent
                String[] toArr = {sending_email_id1, sending_email_id2};
                m.setTo(toArr );
                //Your emailid(from)
                m.setFrom(your_emailId);
                m.setSubject("Subject");
                m.setBody("some body message");

            try {
                if (m.send()) {
                    Log.v("Forgot Password mail", "Success");

                }else {
                    Log.v("Forgot Password mail", "Not Success");
                     }
                } catch (Exception e) {

                Log.e("MailApp", "Could not send email", e.toString());
                }
                    }

                };thread.start();
```

Also create the xml layout and make sure the activity is in your manifest. and tell me if it will help..

Comment: Hi, sir @Ranjit Pati , the attachment part I can upload any file and send to the email I hardcoded?

Comment: sure..just use the `addAttachment(filename)` method like setSubject or  setBody..in parameter just pass the fileneme with its path(e.g `"file://sdcard/xyz/Camera/filename.jpg"` ) ..or just check some tutorials that how to get sdcard filepath.

Comment: If I want it when I click on it, it pop out the select file to upload from different app? instead of I make a path for it?